# Intersection between a horizontal plane and a torus. Problem with complex values

Tags: curves, parametric, plane-geometry, parametrization, intersection-theory

[EDIT: I have replaced $a$ by $R_1$ in my previous post to make your reading and understanding easier, as this is a more general expression.]

I think I have a basic question but I cannot figure out an easy solution.
I am intersecting a torus with an horizontal plane, which I will move from the upper part to the bottom to calculate the area the intersections at different heights. Thus, I need to obtain the parametric curve equation of each intersection to compute the area as: $$A=\int{y(v) x'(v) dv}$$.

My problem is that I am unable to obtain a "closed" parametric curve, since there are certain complex values in the calculation that I cannot avoid. I obtain something like this when I cut the torus in the region between the inner and outter diameters:

[intersection between plane and torus (parametric curve as black line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy2uu.jpg)

[Parametric intersection curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0RVG.jpg)

[Parametric intersection curve plus its negative counterpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGedt.jpg)

As can be seen, even trying to replicate the full geometry by the addition of the negative values parametric curve (just in case this solves something...), there is a small region that does not allow any connection to create a full closed curve to be integrated to obtain the enclosed area.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help a lot.

*Details of my procedure:*

Parametric equations of the torus:
$$ x(u,v) = R_2*\sin(v),$$
$$ y(u,v) = (R_1+R_2\cos(v))\cos(u), $$
$$ z(u,v) = (R_1+R_2\cos(v))\sin(u), $$
with $v \in [0, 2\pi]$, $u \in [0, 2\pi]$, $R_1$ the radial position of the center of the revolutioned circunference, and $R_2$ the radius of the said circunference in revolution.

Parametric equations of the plane:
$$z(x,y)=h,$$
with $h$ an specific height which will be varied. It is just a horizontal plane.

To obtain the parametric curves, I have to make equal both $z$ values:
$$(R_1+R_2\cos(v))\sin(u) = h, $$
Thus: $\sin(u) = \frac{h}{R_1+R_2\cos(v)}$. I can substitute this value in y(u,v) to obtain y(v) by either using $u=\arcsin(\frac{h}{R_1+R_2\cos(v)})$ or $\cos(u)=\sqrt{1-\sin(u)^2}$. By using the latter one, we can get the following parametric curve for the intersection:

$$ x(v) = R_2*\sin(v),$$
$$ y(v) = (R_1+R_2\cos(v))\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{h}{R_1+R_2\cos(v)}\right)^2}, $$
with $v \in [0, 2\pi]$.

When $\left(\frac{h}{R_1+R_2\cos(v)}\right)^2$ > 1, the square root yields the said problematic complex values.

Many thanks in advance for your time to read this post.

Best regards.

[EDIT: An easy working Matlab script to visualize this situation:]

```
close all;
R1=3; R2=1;
h=3.7; %Example of height
L1=4; L2=4; %some limits for the plane   

%Plane equation
syms u v
yp=v;
zp = h;
xp = u;
fsurf(xp, yp, zp, [-(L1 + 2*R1)/2, (L1 + 2*R1)/2 , -(L2 + 2*R2)/2, (L2 + 2*R2)/2], 'LineStyle', ls, 'FaceColor', 'm'); hold on;


%Torus equation
syms u v
%a=R1+R2; 
x_t = R2*sin(v);
y_t = (R1+R2*cos(v))*cos(u);
z_t = (R1+R2*cos(v))*sin(u);
fsurf(x_t, y_t, z_t, [0, 2*pi, 0, 2*pi], 'LineStyle', ls, 'FaceColor', 'g'); 

%Intersection
syms v
x_i = R2*sin(v);
y_i = (R1+R2*cos(v)).*(sqrt(1-(h/(R1+R2*cos(v)))^2) ) ;
z_i=h+v-v; %tricky to plot a 2D plot in a 3D figure
fplot3(x_i,y_i,z_i, [0, 2*pi], 'k-', 'LineWidth', 4); xlabel('x')
hold on

syms v
x_i = R2*sin(v);
y_i = -(R1+R2*cos(v))*(sqrt(1-(h/(R1+R2*cos(v)))^2) ) ;
z_i=h+v-v; %tricky to plot a 2D plot in a 3D figure
fplot3(x_i,y_i,z_i, [0, 2*pi], 'k-', 'LineWidth', 4); xlabel('x')
hold on
```

Comment: Is it possible that those values of $h$ correspond to non-intersections?

Comment: @preferred_anon Thanks for your reply. No, I am pretty sure there is intersection, as shown in the figures

Comment: Your [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHDnX.png) seems to go away in geogebra.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thank you so much for your valuable response!!! I wonder whether this is a consequence of MATLAB precision (e.g. sqrt(1-1.000001) yields a complex number rather than 0). How is v varied in your Geogebra computation? Between 0 and 2pi too? Best regards

Comment: That's right. The commands used are Curve and Surface.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland If you are sweeping from 0 to 2*pi then it is weird... because for the values set in your Geogebra example, you have sqrt( 1 - (2.3/(3+cos(v)))^2 ). If v is, for instance, v=2.792 rad (that is, 160 degrees), then you have a complex value: 0.0000 + 0.4960i !

Comment: The points that show up do make up the half of the curve (the other half coming from the negative square root). And you're right the values from about $v\in (2.3,4)$ don't contribute.

Comment: Many thanks for all of your responses, @Jan-MagnusØkland. After creating my own Geogebra simulation and trying other ways in MATLAB to plot this, I can confirm that my problem was only present in MATLAB visualisation using fplot/fplot3 for parametric plotting. As you suggest, complex number simply do not contribute and this happens for certain values of $h$, $R1$ and $R2$, easily identifiable as I said in my question. I hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a Geogebra simulation and trying other ways in MATLAB to plot this (simply to use the standard plot() command), I can confirm that my problem was only related to visualisation in MATLAB when using fplot()/fplot3() for parametric plotting. My "issue" with complex numbers simply had nothing to do with this. These numbers do not contribute to the plot. I hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using the cartesian equation of the torus
$$
\left(R_2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2+z^2=R_1^2
$$

you can arrive at an equation of the form
$$
y=f(x,z)
$$

Comment: I would need in principle the parametric equations, since my problem is more complicated (I create pieces of torus joined to other volumes, controled by the angles v and u in the equations above). However, your suggestion may be interesting in case I am desperated not being able to solve this!